# Facebook messenger - add extension to drawer

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, chatbot

I've got a basic (test) FB messenger bot working in PHP.  I can receive messages and reply to them - all working fine.

I've been reading about chat extensions - where you can add an icon to the drawer that triggers a web component.  I've gone through the documentation, but can't seem to make it work.

I've created a basic "hello world" page (just to test the concept) and tried to make this the home URL [as described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/home-url/#post).  The domain is whitelisted and I get all the appropriate "success" responses (and when I do the status check calls, they give back the right details), but I'm not seeing anything in the drawer when I chat to the bot as a test user (on an iPhone).

I'm also not seeing anything attempting to load the "hello world" page at any time.  Am I missing something fundamental here?  What's the correct technique for making this appear?

Many thanks,

David

Comment: With lags between messenger ui and your settings, usually deleting the convo and starting over is the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Cracked it!  Was looking for it during a conversation with my own bot.  It only appears in personal conversations elsewhere *after* having a conversation with the bot.